# Angular 2 Setup in visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core

I want to setup angular 2 in asp.net core 1.1 in visual studio 2017 RC with latest type script and angular 2 I tried with some of the blog. However, I am facing lots of issue. Can I get the step - by step process to setup in visual studio 2017 (Asp.net core 1.1). I don't want to use template.

Here is the few setup I,have done. However, I am getting an **Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:16770/traceur**

**System.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what kind of problem you are facing?

Comment: Please can you provide me the step by step process to setup

Comment: there are some changes in visual studio 2017 for dotnet core. You can prefer [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/12/12/updating-visual-studio-2017-rc-net-core-tooling-improvements/) this link.

Comment: I have added some code. i, am getting an error. Please can you resolve this issue

Comment: I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435677/error-xhr-error-404-not-found-loading-http-localhost3622-app-js-angul) will help you. This is also same problem which is already answered. Can you please try this method once.

Comment: No it didn't help ..... same problem